# how to add New Line while writing byte array to file

Tags: c#

Hi I am reading a audio file into a byte array. then i want to read every 4 bytes of data from that byte array and write it into another file.

I am able to do this but, my problem is i want to add new line aft every 4 byte of data is written to file. how to do that??
Here is my code...

```
FileStream f = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\MyTest.acc");
for (i = 0; i < f.Length; i += 4)
{
    byte[] b = new byte[4];
    int bytesRead = f.Read(b, 0, b.Length);

    if (bytesRead < 4)
    {
        byte[] b2 = new byte[bytesRead];
        Array.Copy(b, b2, bytesRead);
        arrays.Add(b2);
    }
    else if (bytesRead > 0)
        arrays.Add(b);

    fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
}
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think this might be the answer to your question:

```
            byte[] newline = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
            fs.Write(newline, 0, newline.Length);
```

So your code should be something llike this:

```
            FileStream f = new FileStream("G:\\text.txt",FileMode.Open);
            for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i += 4)
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[4];
                int bytesRead = f.Read(b, 0, b.Length);

                if (bytesRead < 4)
                {
                    byte[] b2 = new byte[bytesRead];
                    Array.Copy(b, b2, bytesRead);
                    arrays.Add(b2);
                }
                else if (bytesRead > 0)
                    arrays.Add(b);

                fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                byte[] newline = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
                fs.Write(newline, 0, newline.Length);
            }
```

Comment: Hi Nick...aft using newline, when i open the file using Hex Editor New, the data was shown as this ff f1 58 40 0d 0a 28 41 4c 01 0d 0a. after 4 bytes instead of new line it was represented as 0d 0a then aft 4 bytes 0d 0a is shown.

Comment: Well those are byte representations of new line. Open it in notepad you'll see

Comment: okay...yes. i can see the data aftr 4 bytes it is writing into new like....thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Pass `System.Environment.NewLine` to the filestream

For more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx